# How to get value from checked checkbox, which are in a table

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a form:

```
<form action='send.php' method ='post'>
        SMS: <input type='checkbox' name = 'sms'>
        E-mail: <input type='checkbox' name = 'email' id='mailcheck'><br>
        <TEXTAREA NAME='message' WRAP='virtual' COLS='40' ROWS='3'>
        </TEXTAREA><br>
        <input type ='submit' name ='Send' size = '10' value = 'send'>
        </form>
```

I have a table which construct from DB:

```
$table = "<table border=1 width=100% align=center>\n";
        $table .= "<tr>\n";
        $i = 1;
        while ($i < mysql_num_fields($queryResult)) {
            $meta = mysql_fetch_field($queryResult, $i);
            $i++;
            $table .= "<td>".$meta->name."</td>\n";
        }
        $table .= "<td> Выбрать все: <input type='checkbox' name='maincheck' value='main' id='chkSelectAll'</td>\n";
        $table .= "</tr>\n";
        $i = 1;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResult)){     
            $table .= "<tr>\n";
            $table .= "<td>".$row['name']."</td>\n";
            $table .= "<td>".$row['post']."</td>\n";    
            $table .= "<td>".$row['section']."</td>\n";  
            $table .= "<td>".$row['company']."</td>\n";  
            $table .= "<td>".$row['phone_number']."</td>\n";  
            $table .= "<td>".$row['email']."</td>\n";  
            $table .= "<td>".$row['status']."</td>\n";  
            $table .= "<td>".$row['lock_time']."</td>\n";  
            $table .= "<td>".$row['reason_for_blocking']."</td>\n";  
            $table .= "<td><input type='checkbox' class=".check."  name='cbname3[]' id='chkItems' value=".$row['id']." /></td>";
            $table .= "</tr>\n";
            $i++;
        }
        $table .= "</table>\n";
        echo $table;
```

I want to take value of checked checkboxes from table to send.php.

**I cant take this throw $_POST, because it's different forms!**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get value of checked checkbox in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291370/how-to-get-value-of-checked-checkbox-in-php)

Comment: That is another question. There's not one person didn't understand what I asked.

Comment: — so it is the same question, but you expressed yourself badly, so you expressed the rewrite as a new question instead of fixing the existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cant take this throw $_POST, because it's different forms!

With your code as written in the question, the checkboxes are not inside any form and you have only one form.

Put the table inside that form.

Comment: how can i do that if it construct dynamically by query from Db? Can you show please?

Comment: Move the `</form>` tag to after `echo $table`

Comment: @Divers: At its simplest, just remove the `</form>` closing tag and place it after the table.  There may be a little more involved to keep the HTML structurally correct, but the basic premise is to just include the form elements inside the scope of the form tag.

Comment: I do that, but I when i test this using "echo $POST['maincheck'];" in send.php, it shows nothing. Why so?

Comment: Presumably, you didn't check the check box.

Comment: No, problem was in "$POST", not "$_POST". Thank you and sorry.