# getting Checkbox value in php

Tags: php

When I pass the html form having checkboxes to a php page, when I retrieve them I get value `true` for all the boxes that I have checked, and `false` for unchecked boxes. I need to get the value only.

```
<?php 
$contact=$_POST['contact'];

foreach ($contact as $conid){
   echo $conid
}
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268887/php-checkbox-input http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291370/how-to-get-value-of-checked-checkbox-in-php

Comment: Checkboxes are always `TRUE` or `FALSE`, that's the point of them - what value do you want, exactly?

Comment: @DaveRandom: That's not true. They either have their assigned value, or they are not set.

Comment: @DaveRandom only partially true. The checkbox also contains a value, which is only sent if the checkbox is ticked

Comment: @kissmyface OMG I cannot believe I have managed to never know that. I have just tried it and it's true, I have never bothered to try adding a `value=""` attribute to a checkbox before... I'll just shut up I think... :-)

Answer (score 4):

One possible approach is to set names like that:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='box[1]'>
<input type='checkbox' name='box[2]'>
<input type='checkbox' name='box[3]'>
```

This way you could access them in PHP with

```
foreach ($_POST['box'] as $id=>$checked){
    if ($checked =='on')
        //process your id
}
```

The second approach is more clean, I think. Set value's attributes on checkboxes:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='box[]' value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' name='box[]' value='2'>
<input type='checkbox' name='box[]' value='3'>
```

With this you'll receive only checked values:

```
foreach ($_POST['box'] as $id){
        //process your id
}
```

Comment: Your first approach isn't correct. `$checked == 'true'` will (always) return false, since for example Chromium sends 'on' if a checkbox was checked. If you set a value for a checkbox, that value will be sent. Using the values and your second approach, it's possible to not only sent IDs, but also associated values. (e.g. `<input type='checkbox' name='box[1]' value='value-for-ID-1'>`)

Comment: Right, FF also sends 'on'. My mistake :) Edited

Comment: You really shouldn't rely on the string, that is sent, if no value was given. Better to just check, which names are sent.

Comment: I'm using the second approach. Always :) But checking the names makes sence too.

Comment: Often I just need a checkbox like 'terms-of-service-accepted', where using the name is the easiest way…

Comment: Sure, but that's not the case for this question.