# Checkbox from HTML to PHP

Tags: php, html

I have asked loads of questions recently but I have just moved from .NET to PHP and struggling to get a grasp on some of the things I am putting together.

I am trying to post a Checkbox result into my PHP script, and then into my DB, it's not working and I don't know why, can anyone point out my mistake:

Snippet of HTML:

```
<form id="person" action="personuploader.php" method="post">
Web <input type="checkbox" name="web" value="Yes" />
<input type="submit" value="Notify Me" name="submit">
```

Snippet of PHP:

```
if ( $_POST['web'] == "Yes")
{
$web = ("Checked");
}
else 
{
$web = ("Unchecked");
}

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (`email`, `type`, `cats`) 
VALUES ('$email','$radio','$web')";
```

I'm not getting SQL errors, and it's not my SQL Query as when I change this to a textbox I can post without an issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you provided?

Comment: I don't get an output from the if statement.

Comment: Well, no output whatsoever.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get value of checked checkbox in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291370/how-to-get-value-of-checked-checkbox-in-php)

Comment: @Dan This code doesn't have anything to generate any output.

Comment: If you want to print `$web`, print it with `echo`. There's also a SQL injection in this code.

Comment: @OleKristianAanensen Is there? Where?

Comment: @Jessica can you explain to me why. I do apologise. Going from .NET MVC to PHP seems to be confusing me!

Comment: @PeteR my bad, it's not. Thought $_POST['web'] was put directly into the query for a second.

Comment: @Dan What do you expect to see outputted to the screen? PHP requires you to specifically say print or echo a string or whatever.

Comment: You also don't have any code to actually execute that sql query. It's just a string.

Comment: @Jessica - I don't want any output other than it creating a variable called: $web which will be put in my DB in the column "cats".

Comment: That isn't output. Creating a variable is not output.

Comment: **You're spamming here.** Same or very similar question/problem 3 times. **Read and learn tutorials, and stop asking questions every 5 minutes**

Comment: @Fred-ii- / I'm not asking questions every 5 minutes :S Sorry if you think I am spamming, not intentional.

Comment: @Jessica I assume he is going to execute that query, i doubt he made this for the lulz. But if you think this A4, yes, in the code over there's no execution of that query.

Comment: A4? As in, the paper size England uses? What?

Assumptions don't do anyone any good.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST['web''])) { 
  // Checkbox is selected 
} else { 
  // Alternate code
 }
```

Checkbox doesnt exists in postdata if it is not checked

Comment: I've tried this with:

`if (isset($_POST['web'])) { 
  $web = ("1");
} else { 
  $web = ("5");
 }`

Comment: What says echo $ web after that?

Comment: Perfect. I realised after I updated this code the first time my Firebug disconnected! Sorry to be an idiot! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if ( isset($_POST['web']))
{
    $web = ("Checked");
}
else 
{
    $web = ("Unchecked");
}
```

or this

```
if ( !empty($_POST['web']))
{
    $web = ("Checked");
}
else 
{
    $web = ("Unchecked");
}
```

Comment: I am seeing the script terminate again in the same place.

Comment: Dan you want to write "checked" into database if checkbox is selected as i understand. this should work

Comment: Hmm, that's the outcome I want. But it's not working.

Comment: try print_r($_POST) or print_r($_REQUEST) and you will see posted data. make sure that you have posted right form.