# Get values in td when checkbox is marked

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I have a query that gets addresses from persons. The data is presented in a table:

```
echo "<div id='rightcontent'><table id='one-column-emphasis'>";
echo "<th><input type='checkbox' name='csv_all' id='csv_all'></th><th>Namn</th><th>Adress</th><th>Adress2</th><th>Adress3</th><th>Personnummer</th><th>Telefonnummer</th><th>Telefonnummer2</th>";
$antal_sidor = round($obj->search->wp->totalHits / $obj->search->wp->pageSize); 

foreach($obj->search->wp->features as $fish) //Loopar ut 50st (pageSize)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='csv' class='csv'></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $fish->name . "</td>";
    foreach($fish->addresses as $ad)
    {
        echo "<td>" . $ad->label . " " . $ad->postcode . " " . $ad->area . "</td>";
    }   
    if(!empty($fish->dateOfBirth))
    {
        echo "<td>" . $fish->dateOfBirth . "</td>";
    }   
    if(!empty($fish->phoneNumbers))
    {
        foreach($fish->phoneNumbers as $ph)
        {
            echo "<td>" . $ph . "</td>";
        }
    }       

    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

As you can see, a checkbox field is listed in the rows. The purpose is to mark all the checboxes, and then export the addresses to CSV. But how do I get the values, the addresses, of the tds, when I select all the checkboxes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get value of checked checkbox in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291370/how-to-get-value-of-checked-checkbox-in-php)

Comment: @AmalMurali: In this case, I dont want to get value from checked checkbox?

Comment: Can you show the HTML output of the table?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: How should I show you that?

Comment: View the source after the page is rendered, copy and paste the result here in your post.

Comment: did you look at all at my fully functioning demo that even has code to generate the table clientside? You can ignore the table code if you do not need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing details, do you want to do this client-side in javascript or server-side with PHP when the form is sent?
For server-side then you need to add a name to your checkbox inputs and that field will be send along with its value to PHP. For client-side then you could insert the data in the DOM first, then use jQuery to find checked inputs and retrieve the data.

```
foreach($obj->search->wp->features as $fish) //Loopar ut 50st (pageSize)
{
    echo "<tr data-phone-numbers='" . json_encode($fish->phoneNumbers) . "' data-addresses='" . json_encode($fish->addresses) . "'>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='csv' class='csv'></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $fish->name . "</td>";
...
```

Then with jQuery just gather the checked inputs and find the encoded addresses:

```
var addressList = [];
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
    addressList.push({
        "phones": JSON.parse($(this).closest("tr").data("addresses")),
        "addresses": JSON.parse($(this).closest("tr").data("phone-numbers"))
    });
});
//addressList now is an array phones and addresses objects for all the checked items
```

On a side note, I don't see how your code will produce well-formed table cells, you have an unpredictable number of TDs in a TR. You might want to re-evaluate your table structure to make sure each row has a fixed amount of cells.

Comment: How can I get the phone numbers from the tds? Not just the addresses?

Comment: Depends how you want the data to show in the end but you can add more data- fields next to data-addresses in the TR. Will update the answer.

Comment: Answer edited with phones and addresses objects. I don't know how all of your $fish objects look like in PHP but you could just json_encode the whole thing instead of the individual addresses, phoneNumbers, etc. Be careful if you have more sensitive data in them though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully functioning version that creates CVS from the checked rows and additinally that takes JSON from the PHP instead of sending a table over the net

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/EeX8g/)

```
$("#csv_all").on("click", function () {
    $(".csv").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
$("#makeCsv").on("click", function () {
    var csv = [];
    $(".csv:checked").each(function () {
        var row = [];
        $(this).parent().siblings().each(function () { // all TDs
            row.push('"' + $(this).text() + '"');
        });
        if (row.length > 0) csv.push(row.join(","));
    });
    $("#csv").val(csv.length > 0?csv.join("\n"):"");

});
```